# Bash Shell Tutorials

Tags: bash, shell, documentation

What are some good bash tutorials? I would like to learn more about the bash shells commands and how to use them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[**Advanced Bash Scripting Guide**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) from The Linux Documentation Project pages.
(Also available as a PDF file if you prefer that).

- [**Recommended online resources for learning bash scripting**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855464/recommended-online-resources-for-learning-bash-scripting)
- [**How to learn your way through Linux’s shell**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451713/how-to-learn-your-way-through-linuxs-shell)

General search tags:

- Stackoverflow: [**bash+scripting**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash+scripting), [**bash+script**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash+script)
- Serverfault: [**bash+scripting**](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bash+scripting), [**bash+script**](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bash+script), etc
- [**Command Line Fu**](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse) -- for quick tricks (think of them as short tutorials)

---

Empty at this time... `:-)`

- Superuser: [**bash+scripting**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash+scripting), [**bash+script**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash+script)

But, don't go by that.

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but I think that the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide is very unfriendly. I never found an answer in that guide. Greg's wiki, and especially the FAQ, as mentioned by spatz, are great for beginners.

Comment: @mrucci, On the contrary, I can remember a large number of times looking up things directly in the guide with Google searches. Meanwhile, Greg's Wiki links referred by `spatz` are good too.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that every time I search google for "bash [something]" I found and follow the ABSG link but very rarely I found an answer in the cryptict, badly organized and presented material.

Comment: Well, there is at least one person finding TLDP ABS Guide less useful -- So, I'm up-voting `spatz's` answer too...

Answer (score 6):

I find Greg's [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) very helpful, even for beginners.

Also, I remember learning bash from Daniel Robbins' series, [Bash by example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash.html), which is a very good read in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind to pay for the best resources in book format:

- http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526788/ (Bash Cookbook)
- http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009656/ (Learning Bash - slightly outdated)
- http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527761/ (bash Quick Reference - I do use it frequently...)
- http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003302/ (Unix power tools - OK, not only bash. But it's a must have)

Answer (score -1):

This is a great video tutorial for command line editing: http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/bash-command-line-editing/